# How do I disable syntax highlighting in the changelist?

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting

I want syntax highlighting off in menus like the changelist (accessed via `:changes`).  Is there a setting for this?

[image: screenshot of :changes list]

[image: screenshot of :reg list]

Comment: I'm not to understand what you mean when you says: "like the changelist"  could you elaborate?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt see screenshot in edits

Comment: this is not possible

Comment: I'm certain it uses a highlight group @ChristianBrabandt, because mine looks different (unless you're saying it uses a terminal color directly, and I'm seeing a different color because of my terminal's palette?)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I also have all of my iTerm colors set to the same thing, so yea I don't think the colors shown above are coming from those settings

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt FWIW I see similar colors when looking at `:reg`ister contents, see latest edits

Comment: @D.BenKnoble well yes, Vim is using the `Directory` highlighting group. But you cannot disable using a highlighting group for this

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt No, but you could change `Directory` to be very plain (at the risk of "breaking" other things).